# Get result in the same Web html page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I m running out of idea to execut my html/php web page.

Here is the scenario :

From a html web page on body section I load a php script wich retrieve data from mysql db in present it in table then return it in the section in the initial web page.
When I got this table there is a link on Id (first column) which suppose by clicking on it give info in an another section on the same page BUT it DOES NOT.
It shows it in another web page the info.

Here is the main html code :

```
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3.css">
<head>
<style>
#header {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
}
#section {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;         
}
#footer {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;    
    text-shadow: 1px 1px;   
}
</style>
<script>
function getStudentStatus(Id) {
    if (Id == "") {
        document.getElementById("StuStat").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("StuStat").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        console.log("looking for :"+Id);
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getStudentStatus.php?StudentId="+Id,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
function getStudentInfo(Id) {
    if (Id == "") {
        document.getElementById("StuInfo").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("StuInfo").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        console.log("looking for :"+Id);
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getStuInfo.php?StudentId="+Id,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}

var intShowResult = setInterval(function() {getStudentStatus("q") },60000);

</script>
</head>
<body onload="getStudentStatus('q')">

<div class="w3-container w3-orange">
  <h1>Student Status</h1> 
  <h4>test bed</h4>
</div>
<br><br><br>

<div id="section">
<p>Result: <span id="StuStat"></span></p>
</div>

<div id="footer">
Copyright © xxxxxx.com
</div>



<div id="StuInfo">
<p>Cycle Info of:<span id="StuInfo"></span></p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas ?
/koul

Answer (score 0):

try removing `onload="getStudentStatus('q')"` from the body tag, comment out `var intShowResult = setInterval(function() {getStudentStatus("q") },60000);`
and try adding this instead to your javascript at the end.

The first call to `getStudentStatus` happens before the page has finished loading so if it does execute successfully there is no container element in the html to accept the response. Ensure the page content has fully loaded before calling the function.

```
function initialise(){
    call getStudentStatus(this,'q');
    setInterval( function() { getStudentStatus('q') }, 60000 );
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',initialise,false);
```

Comment: RamRaider, I 've tried to apply wht you say  but still give a new web doc to show the clicked link (getStudentInfo). The result does not go to  StuInfo section.